# Can't find the redirect 'configuration file'

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I am working on a website, it uses addon domain egcourse.id, and I want to develop it in different domain test.egcourse.com (egcourse.com is the main domain). So the result will be like this:

- public_html

  - egcourse.id
  - test.egcourse.com

but when I try to access test.egcourse.com it redirects me (301 moved permanently) back to egcourse.id.

I have looked in cPanel and it has no redirects configured.
Ok, maybe it's the .htaccess, but everything looks normal:

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Maybe I missed somewhere... but I don't know where to look. Any help will be appreciated.

(and sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0):

Your cpanel must have an option to create sub-domain. Please have a look for that option within the cpanel. Clicking to that option you will have the option to create a sub-domain and list down the root directory of your project under public_html that will be in sync to that specific sub-domain. Regarding the redirects, you might also find a redirects option where you will able to do 301 permanent redirects for your sud-domain. Also, you can do the redirects using the htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newsub.domain.com/ [L,R]
```

Comment: I can already create sub-domain. Actually there are other sub-domains already activated and they work fine.

Comment: Maybe there are some wp config that I missed, since I just copy paste the website, but I will look into your solution first